# Why can omit "contains" in sentence of "Does it matter how large the selection [that you bookmark "contains"] is"?

Tags: sentence-construction

There is a sentence:

`Does it matter how large the selection [that you bookmark "contains"] is`.

I know that the **contains** can be omit, so this sentence is also right: `Does it matter how large the selection [that you bookmark] is`.

May you tell me why this **contains** can be omitted here?

Comment: You've got something wrong here. I can't see any way to include the word "contains" here in the first place, so it makes no sense to talk about "omitting" it. But I also don't really understand how "bookmarking" could be affected by the "size" of anything bookmarked. A bookmark points to a web page, not to a "selection", and the "size" of a web page isn't relevant to the fact of it being bookmarked.

Comment: @FumbleFingers May you tell me why can’t add **contains** here?

Comment: I simply don't see *why* you want to include the word "contains" here. If you're shopping, you could buy a "selection" of different things, in which case it might make sense to say "My [shopping] selection contains bread, washing powder, and toilet rolls". But what does your "bookmarked selection" contain?

Comment: @FumbleFingers “Does it matter how large **the selection that you bookmark** is?" I don't feel this centence is right, for in **the selection that you bookmark** there is **noun + that + noun**. How to understand this construction?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to say. Do you mean "bookmark" as in *Add an entry to your web-browser's "favourite places" list, so you can easily return to some particular web page*? If so, I don't know what it means to talk about how "large" that web page is. Or do you more literally mean *put a physical "place-holder" at a specific page in an actual book*? In which case, are you saying one such bookmark might only be there so you can find *one sentence on the page containing the bookmark*, whereas another bookmark is there so you can quickly re-find a long complicated ***chapter***.

Comment: Do we have to keep talking about bookmarks, that make no sense to me here? Perhaps we could discuss the syntax of *It doesn't matter how expensive the meal that you choose from the menu is; I will pay for it.* I suspect that may cover the same aspects of syntax that are bothering you.

Comment: i.e. - sticking closer to your original example: *Does it matter how expensive the meal that you choose from the menu is?* There's still no reason to think about trying to include the word "contains" there.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  Is the **bookmark** a verb there？

Comment: Where? I've used the past tense verb ***bookmarked*** as an adjective several times above, and ***bookmarking*** once as a "gerund noun" and once as a true "continuous verb participle", but I think every time I've used ***bookmark*** it's just as an ordinary noun. You, on the other hand, only seem to have used ***bookmark*** as a verb. But what has this got to do with using the word "contains" or not?

Comment: In my question sentence, is **bookmark** a verb？ I have seen it as a noun before.

Comment: in the clause ***that you bookmark***, the word ***bookmark*** is definitely a verb, not a noun. You can tell this because if I talk about *a web page that **someone else** bookmarks*, or *a recipe that **she** bookmarks*, I'm "conjugating" the verb ***to bookmark*** for "third person singular" (I go, he goes, I bookmark, she bookmarks,...). Sometimes (not necessarily even *usually*) any given word is much more likely to be used as EITHER a noun OR a verb, but most English words *can* be used as either verbs or nouns, depending on the exact context.

Comment: @FumbleFingers   I know now. Thanks many.